# image base64 corrupt post (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, post, base64, corrupt-data

I'm trying to send a post with several parameters and include an image in base64.

The image coding does it well, I checked the base64 image in a online base64 to image converter and looks like the image is encoded successfully. I can do the post process without any problem, but when I download it, the log shows this error:

> Error: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: 120 extraneous bytes before
>   marker 0xf1
>   Error: ImageIO: JPEG Unsupported marker type 0xf1

I do this in a method

```
jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1f);
imageString = [jpgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

And this is the method that sends the post, which is where I think the error is.

```
- (void)putComment{

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);

    __block int responseCode = 0;

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{



        NSString *requestParams = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"idAdvertiser=%@&idUserDevice=%@&image=%@&text=%@&userName=%@&groups=%@",
                               ADVERTISER_ID, idUserDevice, imageString, texto, userName, groups];
        [requestParams stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
        NSData   *postData = [requestParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//        NSData   *postData = [requestParams dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: URL_COMMENT]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
        [request setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:40];


        NSError *error = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                                 returningResponse: &response
                                                             error: &error];
   });

}
```

The server side works perfectly (tested in an Android app), so the problem is not server related.

Comment: Have You Found Solution Of this, I am getting the same issue...

Comment: im getting same issue. have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You encode your url so no need for this line:

```
    [requestParams stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Remove it and try again.

Also

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: URL_COMMENT]];
```

can be turned to:

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [URL_COMMENT stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

Comment: didn´t work. I do not think the problem is in the url because all parameters are passed to the server without error. But the image is corrupt. You can see it even in the browser.